# WPF AlignCenter command Key Gesture (Ctrl + E) doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

The title explains it all. According to official, up to date documentation from MS, this command's default key gesture is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, however, it doesn't work. The command works in my app like a charm, except it doesn't accept the gesture, which is strange. I have it in menuitem on the main window.

Comment: Have you tried listening to Preview**** version of events to see if something else is not eating up the command?

Comment: Tanveer Badar - I don't know what you mean, but since the key gesture is not even displayed in the menu item (other working commands have it displayed normally), I am almost 100% sure that it's not the case

Comment: Anybody to help? Please?